# Wrapping 'next' and 'previous' functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

In my Rails 4 app, I defined functions in my model than get the (nth) next or previous row in de database, wrapping around the entire database, so that `Item.last.next` will refer to `Item.first`:

```
  def next(n=0)
    following = Item.where("id > ?", self.id).order("id asc") + Item.where("id < ?", self.id).order("id asc")
    following[n % following.length]
  end

  def prev(n=0)
    n = n % Item.count-1
    previous = Item.where("id < ?", self.id).order("id desc") + Item.where("id > ?", self.id).order("id desc")
    previous[n % previous.length]
  end
```

This results in three database queries per method call, and I've learned to keep database queries to a minimum, so I wonder if there is a way do get this result with only one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for seems a bit high level. So let's prepare the basic API at first.

```
def next(n=1)      
  self.class.where('id > ?', id).limit(n).order('id ASC')
end

def previous(n=1)
  self.class.where('id > ?', id).limit(n).order('id DESC')
end
```

Then higher level methods

```
def next_recycle(n=1)
  klass = self.class
  return klass.first if (n = 1 && self == klass.last)
  next(n)
end

def previous_recycle(n=1)
  klass = self.class
  return klass.last if (n == 1 && self == klass.first)
  previous(n)
end
```

You can pick methods according to needs.

Comment: Edit -- Thanks, Actually pretty helpful to see you in action. :-)

Comment: Wait, I'm thinking about it :) previous should be okay now.

Comment: But what about:
\* Deleted items that will cause a gap in the id range 
\* Wrapping. `Item.last.next` will return `nil`, but should return `Item.first`.

Comment: Mattern, refactored so it works as expected, though it counldn't reach the first one if the current is last. But I think that's a more advance requirements which need such basic methods at first.